# What is the volume of this triangular pyramid?

Tags: volume, solid-geometry

Given a pyramid, the base is a isosceles triangle $ABC$ where $AB=AC=10$ and $BC=12$. All lateral faces of the pyramid ( triangles) have altitudes equal to $20$. Find the volume of this pyramid.

Comment: What have you tried? What tools do you have available? Especially: do you have access to trigonometric functions?

Comment: There's actually a formula for the volumes of pyramids.  Have you tried looking it up.  I can never remember it (well, I can if you hold a gun to my head) but you can derive it from calculus straightforwardly.

Comment: "All lateral faces of the pyramid ( triangles) have altitudes equal to 20"  That means if you propped them up perpendicularly they would have altitude of 20 feet?  Or does it mean the pyramid is 20 ft? Change my mind you do need some insight then just a formula.  But with trigonometry it isn't hard.

Comment: If their altitudes are of equal length, then they would be congruent, which contradicts the hypothesis. If rather you mean to say that the perpendicular distance between the vertex of the pyramid and its base is $20$, then simply find the area of the base by Heron's formula and apply the ancient pyramid volume formula $$\frac13\times A\times h,$$ where $A$ is the area of the base and $h$ the height of the pyramid.

Comment: $V=\frac{10\ 12\ 20}{3}=800$ from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(geometry)

Comment: Equal altitude does not mean congruency - it means a kind of tilted pyramid.

Comment: The suggested solution is TOTALLY of Mariusz

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$AB < 20$, therefore an altitude with length $20$ in $\triangle ABD$ can be drawn only from the vertex $D$. Denote the foot of this altitude by $E$, and the foot of the altitude of the pyramid by $H$. $E$ and $H$ are different because the other two lateral altitudes also have length $20$. Now we have two lines in the plane $DEH$ orthogonal to $AB$ (the line $DE$ and the line through $E$ parallel to $DH$), therefore the plane $DEH$ is orthogonal to $AB$, and $EH \perp AB$.

Similarly, the altitudes in $\triangle ACD$ and $\triangle BCD$ are the altitudes to $AC$ and $BC$, and if $DF \perp AC$ and $DG \perp BC$, then $FH \perp AC$ and $GH \perp BC$.

The altitudes of the faces are equal, therefore $EH = FH = GH$, and $H$ is the incenter of $\triangle ABC$. From this,
$$V = \frac 1 3 S_{\triangle ABC} \sqrt {DE^2 - r_{\triangle ABC}^2} =
16 \sqrt {391}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short version of Maxim's answer:

The three sides of the base triangle $\triangle$ are tangents to the sphere $S$ of radius $20$ centered at the apex of the pyramid.  Therefore $S$ intersects $\triangle$ in its incircle of radius $\rho={A\over s}$, whereby $A=48$ is the area of $\triangle$ and $s=16$ its semiperimeter. The height $h$ of the pyramid is then given by $h=\sqrt{400-\rho^2}=\sqrt{391}$, so that we obtain the volume $V={1\over3} A\,h=16\sqrt{391}$.